# Starting out with Armory - can I make it go faster?

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization, armory, windows

Does anyone know of a way to make Armory do an initial sync any faster?  I've downloaded the blockchain but so far it's been processing/synchronizing with the network for 17 hours, and it claims it has 11 hours more to go, but I suspect it will be even longer than that.

I have a first generation Core I5 processor, running Windows 10.

I notice that bitcoind is capping out at around ~48% CPU usage, so it only seems to be using two cores.  Any way of tweaking this to use more CPU, or go faster in general?

Comment: Up until block height 300,000 the sync is effectively single threaded, there's not much you can do to try and speed it up.

Comment: What version of bitcoind are you using? Headers first should make the synchronization a lot faster. Also, it's most likely that bitcoind is slow in synchronizing, not Armory.

Comment: I just installed everything fresh two days ago, so whatever version of bitcoind comes with Bitcoin Core 0.11.1.    It's now 48 hours since I started and it's moved onto the third step - "Building Databases", which is currently 64% completed.... o.O.   CPU profile has changed to ArmoryQt.exe using 25% of CPU.... so again it seems core limited.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no solution for that.
You could try to download the blockchain externally but, it's not recommended given that you would not verify if the content is legit.
Take a look at a specific topic related to your question
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1310261.0

Comment: I agree unless you have a military style (ultra fast) internet connection, you will not be able to download the data quickly. It will take a while.